# How long does a lifetime license last?

Tags: licensing, legal-terms

Years ago, I bought a Lifetime license, about $250 for a wordpress theme. I hadn't visited the company for a while, but yesterday saw that what I bought is no longer available for sale, no new updates etc. [image]

Instead, the seller (really just one guy running the show, as far as I can tell), has used the code and relaunched a new product. When I questioned this on a forum I still was able to access, my account was deleted.

In terms of the law, what does "lifetime" really mean? I realize that companies go out of business, so it's their lifetime, not mine, but this seems very different. Is my expectation (of being grandfathered into the new product) unreasonable?

Comment: "I realize that companies go out of business, so it's their lifetime, not mine" Not necessarily.

Comment: @ohwilleke - thx for the edit. My point, if any, is that I understand a business may not be around forever. And that a TiVo, for example, offers lifetime service for the hardware, which will certainly die, as electronics do. Just a distinction, here.

Comment: "License" by default means permission to use, and presumably you still have permission to use the version of the product that you still have.  Did your purchase specifically say that it included more than that (support, updates, something else)?  Was there a written contract, ToS, etc, that may be more specific as to what you are entitled to?  That would generally supersede whatever generic meaning "lifetime" might have.

Comment: There is a story that some time in the 70s a company bought a lifetime license for all Microsoft software, for something like $50,000, and they received free copies of all Microsoft software since then. This was at a time when Microsoft was tiny and it was good money for them.

Comment: @NateEldredge - Just like software that is known to require updates when the OS it's running on changes, Wordpress themes 'break' over time if not tended to. I do not have the original agreement, but I don't think my assumption that lifetime means both support and updates. My issue is that, in effect, the next update was a name change and letting lifetime customers move on. To be clear, the annual customers simply downloaded the new product, and continue to use it.

Comment: But my assumption would be that the *license* only means that you are entitled to keep using the software without committing copyright infringement, and there's no dispute that you retain that right.  A license does not automatically include any guarantee that the software will actually keep working  - that would be a *warranty*.